# converting javascript program from json to xml

Tags: javascript, xml, json, type-conversion

I am rewriting a javascript program that uses json files to one that uses xml files for the settings. The xml files that I have do not have the same structure as the json files and some of the json variables I intend to hard code into the program. I am thinking it would be easiest not recode all of the calls to the json data, so I am trying to create objects that look like the json data and have my own functions to load the xml data into the objects where needed.

Note I have never messed with json before. if you think there may be a better approach I would be happy to try it.

Simple json files I have figured out, just make a class that looks the same.

```
 {
"logo": "yes",
"title": "Jordan Pond",
"author": "Matthew Petroff",    
"license": 1,    
"preview": "../examples/examplepano-preview.jpg",
}
```

turns into

```
function config(){
    this.logo='yes';
    this.title='Jordan Pond';
    this.author='Matthew Petroff';
    this.license='1';
    this.preview='./examples/examplepano-preview.jpg';
}
config= new config();
alert(config.title);
```

Do that and all of the calls to the json stuff works the same as always. I am stumped on the more complicated json files such as

```
{
"default": {
    "license": 0,
    "logo": "no",
    "author": "Kvtours.com",
    "firstScene": "WilsonRiverFishingHole",
    "title": "Wilson"
},
"scenes": {
    "pond": {
        "title": "Jordan Pond",
        "preview": "../examples/examplepano-preview.jpg",
        "panorama": "../examples/examplepano.jpg"
    }
}
}
```

I would think that should convert to something like this.

```
function tourConfig(){
this.default= function() {
    license= "0";
    logo= "no";
    author= "Kvtours.com";
    firstScene= "pondCube";
    title= "Wilson";
}
this.scenes= function(){
    this.pondCube= function() {
        this.title= "Jordan Pond (Cube)";
        this.preview="examples/examplepano-preview.jpg";
        this.panorama="../examples/examplepano.jpg";
    }
}
}
tourConfig= new tourConfig();
alert(tourConfig.default.author);
```

That is not working. Any thoughts on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused on javascript closure.

I think what you want is as follow:

```
function tourConfig(){
    var that = this;
    this.default= function() {
        that.license= "0";
        that.logo= "no";
        that.author= "Kvtours.com";
        that.firstScene= "pondCube";
        that.title= "Wilson";
    }
    // as well as scenes method
}
```

Comment: How is that different than what I have?